# Minimising "touching" the database when loading only unique data from excel (eg "get_or_add" functionality) with SQLalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a better way to do `get_or_add()` without having to hit the database for every check?

I am loading an sqlite database from many (thousands) of excel report files and am looking to reduce duplication. For example, I have around 10,000 excel files, each with around 1,000 rows. In all of these rows, one column appears to be standard (~150 distinct strings across all the files).

**Working flow: The following works but it is VERY slow due to all queries to the database - the vast majority of these Messages shouldn't need to be added to the database:**

```
def get_or_create(session, model, **kwargs):
    instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if instance:
        return instance
    else:
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        session.add(instance)
        session.commit()
        return instance

// ....

for report in reports:
    for row in report:
        record=Record(domain=row[0], identifier=row[1], count=row[2], vendor=row[3], product=row[4])
        if row[5]:
           _message = get_or_create( db.session, Message, messagetext=row[5] )
           record.message = _message
        report.records.append(record)
    db.session.add(report)                
db.session.commit()
```

### Update to clarify the question (2021-03-12):

Following the comments, I have been trying to create an in-memory lookup using lists. I had tried `Set()` but from what I understand, we can't rely on the order of `index` items inSets.. which I need to syncronise with the database table ID. I have also tried disabling `autoflush` as recommended which helped get over one "bump" but I am still unable to create new Message records. I assume I need to specify something like the following... however, I do not understand how to set `_message` as a reference to an existing instance and not create a duplicate record with the same string:

```
    db.session.autoflush = False
    // ...
        if d[5]:
            if d[5] not in messages:
                messages.append( d[5] )
            _message = Message(id=messages.index( d[5]),  messagetext=d[5] )
            detail.message = _message
    // ...
    db.session.autoflush = True
```

The error I get is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: message.id
[SQL: INSERT INTO message (id, messagetext) VALUES (?, ?)]
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't want to commit immediately in the "create" case, but you want to obtain a primary key?

Comment: I'm not so worried about that as that would only be ~150 "touches" to the database - I'm looking to see if I can avoid having to "touch" the database for every record just to check if the text string exists in the database table already

Comment: Your dict/set approach certainly sounds reasonable, especially if you are currently running essentially the same query over and over for each of the ~10_million source rows. Please [edit] your question to better explain what you mean by "I can't work out how to .add() instances manually with a primary key(!)".

Comment: @GordThompson Good point thank you - I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: You certainly seem to be on the right track (although I would use a `set()` instead of a `dict()` because lookups are faster) but I still don't quite "get" what the problem is unless it's what @snakecharmerb mentioned in the first comment. If you need to add a new message you can just create the new object, add it to the session, and then flush the session. That will create the new "id" value that you can store in the set() and use for other purposes if needed.